# connect to Active directory server 636 port using LDAP library in c++

Tags: c++, active-directory, ldap, llvm

I am trying to connect to active directory server with 636 port (secure connection). I have added "#include "ldap_ssl.h" this header. I have used prebuilt libraries downloaded from microfocus official site.

But while calling the any of the ldap_ssl APIs with the below line:

```
int rc = ldapssl_client_init(NULL, NULL);
```

I get the below error:

```
lld-link: error: unknown file type: x64\Release\ssl_init.obj
```

Please suggest If I have to enable or add any other extra library in order to call ldap_ssl APIs.

Thanks for the help

Comment: ***lld-link: error: unknown file type: x64\Release\ssl_init.obj*** What compiler are you using?? It seems like the real problem has nothing to do with ldap and is that the linker you use does not know what a msvc obj file is.

Comment: I am using LLVM 64 bit based on MSVC2019 compiler in Qt creator IDE